# autoescape not working as expected

Tags: django

Im trying to use the autoescape feature of Django and for reason its not working as expected. Below is the code, I tried the autoescape on and even the ESCAPE feature..

Input Name to the form -    `<i>Jacob</i>`

Expected output - `&lt;i&gt;Jacob&lt;/i&gt;`

```
html

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    This is a test page
    {% if display_form %}
        <form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            FIRST NAME : <input type="text" name="fname">
            <input type="submit" value="register"/>
        </form>
    {% else %}
        {% autoescape on %}
        {{ firstname|escape }}
        {% endautoescape %}
    {% endif %}

    </body>
    </html>

views.py

def test_page(request):
    print 'request.method =', request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'request.post = ', request.POST['fname']
        variables = RequestContext(request,{'display_form':False,'firstname':request.POST['fname']})
        return render_to_response('test_page.html',variables)
    else:
        variables = RequestContext(request,{'display_form':True})
        return render_to_response('test_page.html',variables)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`cgi.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) function:

Ex:

```
import cgi
cgi.escape('<i>Jacob</i>')
>>>'&lt;i&gt;Jacob&lt;/i&gt;'
```

In your `views.py`

```
import cgi

def test_page(request):
    print 'request.method =', request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'request.post = ', request.POST['fname']
        variables = RequestContext(request,{'display_form':False,'firstname':cgi.escape(request.POST['fname'])})
        return render_to_response('test_page.html',variables)
    else:
        variables = RequestContext(request,{'display_form':True})
        return render_to_response('test_page.html',variables)
```